# When i used xcode SourceControl push to git then it says "The server SSL certificate failed to verify."

Tags: xcode, git

[GIT PUSH ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z1KU.png)

i just delete some repositories account in xcode preference, then when i push my git to server, it says that.

Answer (score 2):

Try configuring the global git option to work around this (from the [`git-config`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) manual page):

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me. i google that and it tell me that edit file .git/config url = htts://username:passwd@github.com/xxxx/xx.git. then i push successfully.  thank you all the same.